# How to show a calender for a Hotel Management System?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, calendar, swingx

How to show a calender for a Hotel Management System?

I need to make an application that allows the management of a Hotel, i would like to draw in the interface a calender which contains the dates and rooms, so the user can see which  room is available for which date.

I use Java Swing, in Netbeans.

```
  calenderPanel.setLayout( new BorderLayout() );
  JXDatePicker date = new org.jdesktop.swingx.JXDatePicker(Locale.FRANCE);
  JXMonthView m = new JXMonthView();
  m.setFirstDayOfWeek(1);
  m.setDayForeground(6, Color.red);
  m.setDayForeground(5, Color.GREEN);

  Date fl = new Date(114, 0, 5);
  Date fl2 = new Date(114, 0, 6);

  Date[] tab = new Date[] {fl,fl2} ;

  m.setFlaggedDates(tab);
  m.setFlaggedDayForeground(Color.BLUE);

  calenderPanel.add(m, BorderLayout.CENTER);

  JPanel sud = new JPanel();
  calenderPanel.add(sud, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
```

The problem is that I can't show any other information in this calendar.

Comment: *"I can't show any other information in this calendar."*  ***In*** the calendar, or ***around*** the calendar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I need to make an application that allows the management of a Hotel, i
>   would like to draw in the interface a calender which contains the
>   dates and rooms, so the user can see which room is available for which
>   date.

`JXDatePicker` is intended to use as is, you cannot add any information **in** the calendar. But you can listen to selection changes and show available rooms in other components such as [JList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html) or [JTable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) or even [JComboBox](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html).

#### Adding an ActionListener

```
JXDatePicker picker = new JXDatePicker();
picker.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // implementation here
    }
});
```

#### Adding a PropertyChangeListener

```
JXDatePicker picker = new JXDatePicker();
picker.addPropertyChangeListener("date", new PropertyChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent e) {
        // implementation here
    }
});
```

Comment: thank you, so i'll have to work with a JTable to show my informations, i think there's no other option, thanks again!

Comment: @AmineMinou you're welcome! No, in this case there's no option. But most of sites and application work in this way, it's pretty standard.